# Why joint distribution exercise goes wrong

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

Could anyone tell me what went wrong please. Don`t understand.
I have an exercise:
$$
f(x)=3x \\
0 < y < x < 1\\
Find\\
P(X > \frac12 | Y > \frac13)
$$
I found that:
$$
P(X > \frac12 | Y > \frac13)=\frac{P(X>\frac12\cap Y > \frac13)}{P(Y>\frac13)}
$$
which implies to:
$$
\frac{\int_\frac12^1\int_\frac13^x3x}{[marginal PDF_y] \int_\frac13^1\frac{3-y^2}{2}}
$$
for the upper part I get $$\frac12$$ and for the bottom $$\frac{68}{81}
 \\
\frac12\div\frac{68}{81}=\frac{81}{136}$$
which is not right answer.
Explain please what I did wrong. My teacher insists that I should use the marginal distribution in the denominator.

Comment: checked it with the matlab and got again 68/81

Comment: The marginal density for $Y$ is given by
$$
\int_y^1 3x\ \mathsf dx = 3(1-y^2)/2.
$$
You have $(3-y^2)/2$ which is different.

Comment: Okei. Found. Thanx for hint. Going to check now. That was stupid question because of that mistake :)